# Can only animate once with Animation

Tags: android

I have an Animation that animates properly and correct **the first time I'm running it**.

But in my application I have a Button and when I click on that I want to animate exactly as I did the first time, but instead its not animating at all.

Any ideas? Don't think this is code related, its seems that I'm missing something from the API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use `getAnimation().start();` for your view. It will restart your animation.

Answer (score 7):

When you are using ViewPropertyAnimator without xlm code, you must remember that:

When you are animating a view with a rotation (or anithing else) viewElement.animate.rotate(180), **you will change the viewElement attribute** in this case rotation!

So if you call again viewElement.animate.rotate(180). Your element will not rotate, cause the rotation is already occured

Solution 1

```
myView.animate().rotation(myView.getRotation()+180);
```

Solution 2 (seems equivalent but is different)

```
myView.animate().setRotation(0);
myView.animate().rotation(180);
```

Answer (score 3):

set `v.startAnimation(animation);` instead of `v.setAnimation(animation);` 
its working for me

Comment: I think this is a better way to solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (animation appeared only once) and `getAnimation().start();` unfortunately did not work. I solved it by invoking `clearAnimation()` on that view object and after that I set that anim again. It doesn't look like the most elegant and efficient solution, but at least works...

Answer (score 1):

Might help someone, but my issue had to do with setting `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` on my parent view. Once I removed that, my views started animating multiple times again. Must be some weird animation overriding thing.

Comment: Wow, you made my life better with this

Answer (score 0):

Just Try This Way. I solved this and now Its working for me

```
 nextAnimObject= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.animation_layout);
 layout.clearAnimation();
 layout.setAnimation(nextAnimObject);
 layout.getAnimation().start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution.

```
viewElement.animate.rotate(180);
```

The comment above says that `viewElement.animate.rotate(180)` is done once. But `rotationBy(180)` is actually performed relative to the object's current position.